# Span блоки перемещаются при наведении на ссылку - глюк в Opera

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, opera

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть страница http://yarfeliks.ru/tytan_pr.php 
на ней имеются блоки с продукцией.

Во всех браузерах вёрстка отображается нормально, **но при просмотре в браузере Opera** - если навести курсор на кнопку-ссылку: Описание или Купить и делать это раз за разом, span блоки красного цвета с информацией об объеме (750 мл) начинают уползать вверх, причём уползают все блоки кроме того к которому относятся кнопки.

Предположил было, что дело в скриптах, по удалял... то же самое.Подскажите пожалуйста в чём дело, как исправить ситуацию.

Comment: Проблема в стилях. Проверьте правильность установления `line-height` и `font-size`, `float` и `clear`. [Источник](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/4370386.htm).

Comment: @Crasher Спасибо за подсказку, но никак не могу найти где именно..

Comment: эх, еще один сайт на бутстрап...